# Upload TCPDF file to backblaze?

Tags: php, symfony, http, tcpdf, backblaze

I'm building an API using Symfony and I am trying to upload a generated file directly in a Backblaze bucket. I'm struggling to build the request and send the file.

Here is the code of my endpoint :

```php
$filename = "fiche-technique_".str_replace(' ','-',$product->getName())."_".date("Y-m-d").".pdf";
$pdf = $exportService->PDF_Recipe($product,$recipe,$user);
$upload = $httpService->uploadPDF($user,$pdf,$filename,"product_recipe/");
$test = json_decode($upload);
return new JsonResponse($test, 200, [], true);
```

Note that $pdf is generated using `Output('','S')`. Then, here is my `uploadFile()` function :

```php
public function uploadPDF(User $user,$file,$filename,$folder)
    {   
        $upload = $this->getUploadUrl($user);

        $client = HttpClient::create([
            "headers"=>[
                'Authorization' => $upload["authorizationToken"],
                'X-Bz-File-Name' => "oui.pdf",
                'X-Bz-Content-Sha1'=> sha1($file),
                'Content-Length' => strlen($file),
                'Content-Type' => "application/pdf"
            ]
        ]);
        $response = $client->request('POST',$upload["uploadUrl"].'/b2api/v2/b2_upload_file',[
            'body'=>$file
        ]);

        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        $content = $response->getContent();

        return $content;
    }
```

I'm 100% sure that my `uploadUrl()` function is working. But I'm getting a 400 error. My first struggle is to actually show the Backblaze API response, actually when I try my endpoint in postman I just get a 500 error with that message `"HTTP/1.1 400  returned for \"MYUPLOADURL"."`
But if I build my request myself in postman, get the upload irl and attach a file, it works well, and when not I have a detailed response with what's wrong (wrong header or anything like that).

How can I make my endpoint to actually show me the real response from Backblaze ? And how to actually manage to send a pdf file as a string ?

Comment: Sounds like the request getting a 400 response causes an exception - which you are not catching anywhere, eventually resulting in a 500 error from _your_ system. So go catch the exception, and check what the actual response body contained in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user that commented, I found that the Symfony's Http Client is set to throw an exception for any response with a status code between 300 and 599. To avoid that and see what's wrong in your request you have to call the `$response->getContent()` or `$response->toArray()` with false as an argument.

In my case, using `getContent(false)` allowed me to see that I just mis writted the url in my request :) `$upload["uploadUrl"].'/b2api/v2/b2_upload_file'` is supposed to be just `$upload["uploadUrl"]` because the Backblaze API return the full upload url when asked.

Thanks !